# DW Q$A plugin answers into Ultimate member plugin profile tab

Tags: wordpress, plugins, ultimate-member

I am using DW Q&A plugin for website and its having a profile option for users also where total answers of user show under answers tab.

I am using ultimate member plugin for users registration but it has its own separate profile page.
But answers of users don't show in comments tab because those answers are being recorded in DW Q&A plugin.

I want to show a new tab in utlimate member plugin profile that can fetch answers of DW Q&A plugin and list them.

Any expert ?

I tried my best to manually edit the class of both plugins but its not working.